# CDATA Section Node deprecated in DOM4

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, w3c

I have been doing some reading on the DOM documents and it seems that in the new standard the node type for CDATA sections is now gone.

Seems that [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) got rid of `CDATA_SECTION_NODE` since it is now deprecated. In the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-dom-20121206/#interface-node) document
now it says that its historical. My question is: If now the function `nodeType` does not detect the `CDATA_SECTION_NODE` how does the DOM deal with those tags? That is if I were to write

```
<script><![CDATA[ /*Some code with < & and what not */ ]]></script>
```

then how will the browsers deal with this if there is no node to handle the CDATA sections? Does it simply read the contents and ignores the `<!CDATA[` and `]]>` strings?

Furthermore, is there anywhere that explains the decision to get rid of it?

Comment: Try it yourself. Create an element, add CDATA stuff to it, and iterate through its children, checking the node type and value

Comment: @Ian: I have tested this in Firefox, it seems that everything inside `<! >` is treated as a "bogus" comment when viewing an HTML file. Surprisingly though, if I put a cdata section in an xml document then when inspecting the elements I see that it detected a cdata-section node. I'm not so sure what javascript will say about that node when reading the xml file which contains it. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: CDATA is specific to SGML and XML, it is not valid in HTML and never has been, so it is correct and expected behavior that it appears as a "bogus" comment, because a "proper" comment has `<!--` and `-->`.  However, I am still confused about what exactly has changed.  For example, if there is no CDATA in the new DOM4, yet the CDATA tag still exists in XML, then how will we process the data once Mozilla obsoletes and removes DOM support?  I.e. a tree walker looking for NodeFilter.SHOW_CDATA_SECTION will fail?  So then how to we find them?  it only works now because it's not yet obsolete/removed.

Comment: I assume CDATA is just treated like any other text node (or part of text node)

Comment: I have some XML of the form `<outertag><tags><innertag><!CDATA[<p>some HTML etc</p>]]></innertag></tags>[more <tags> here]</outertag>` opened in browser from local file system.  In the Browser Console (CTRL-k): JS DOM `document.createTreeWalker( document, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null );`  Then this `<tags>.textContent` shows the HTML.  Or this `<tags>.childNode[0].nodeValue` has the HTML.  But if `childNode[0]` is a `CDATASection` node, then exactly what was removed in DOM4?  I thought CDATASection nodes will be removed?  Is FF 49 not using DOM4 yet?  Or not yet removed?  Will be removed when?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few distinct components to CDATA handling:

1. Whether CDATA is a distinct node type in the DOM (a [`CDATASection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection) interface with a `Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE` [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)) or whether it's just a Text node.
2. How the (HTML or XML) parser handles the markup containing `<!CDATA[ ... ]]>` -- how does it treat the special characters (`<>&`) inside CDATA, does it emit a single node for the CDATA section, and if so does it create a `Text` node or a `CDATASection` node in the DOM.
3. How the CDATA sections are serialized (wrapped in `<![CDATA[ ]]>` or with special characters escaped)

As far as I can tell for #2 the HTML5 parser spec is implemented in most browsers and according to it, the parser never emits CDATASection nodes and depending on the context

- either parses the content of the CDATA as "raw text" (with different handling of special characters) - e.g. inside the `<script>` or `<math>`
- or treats the CDATA as a "bogus comment", [which ends at the first `>`](https://bug98304.bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=435969#c3).

The question of how and if CDATA should be exposed in the DOM is not agreed upon and despite being removed from the DOM4 spec, it is still available in at least Gecko (see [Mozilla bug 660660](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=660660), W3C bugs [12841](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12841) and [27386](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=27386)).

- On one hand, from the point of view of an application working with the DOM the CDATA node is not much different from a text node -- the only difference is their serialization in the markup. So if CDATA is exposed as a separate node type, everyone needs to remember to check for it any time they want to check for a text node.
- On the other hand, losing the ability to serialize certain sections of the document as CDATA upsets the developers and users of authoring tools, because it forces the serialization to always encode characters special to XML/HTML.